# django admin project many to many relationship

Tags: django, admin

Looking for some advice/tips on a django project I am working on.

Scenario:
A sporting club runs their events once a week. They need to keep a track of their membership database and individual events. I am hoping to do this through django admin.

Currently I have designed it using two Django apps: members and eventdays
The member app has a model.py like:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    addedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    memberEventDay = models.ManyToManyField('eventdays.EventDay')
```

The eventday app has the model

```
class EventDay(models.Model):
    organiser = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    dateRan = models.DateField('Event Date',blank=True,null=True)
```

I wish for the user/admin to be able to iteratively add members to a certain eventday by accessing member names from a drop down list populated by the membership database. And for each person at a given eventday, i would like to register information like MoneyCollected, TimeSpent etc. As a summary for the event day, i would also like the TotalMoneyCollected displayed - updated everytime I edit individual members and their spending for the day.

I like to keep the manytomanyfield so that for each member i can track which eventdays he/she has attended and for each eventday, i can have a list of riders.

Using ForeignKey field instead of manytomanyfield and using inline view in admin.py allowed me to get the option to easily add and delete attendees easily, but i wish to achieve the same with the manytomanyfield.

I figure what I have written up is pretty vague so if you don't understand anything please let me know.

Should i step out of admin mode and just work with views.py instead?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you can do most (maybe all) of what you want in admin - so give it a try and maybe extend it to one or two views if needed.

For your ManyToMany-Field, you can use the same widgets as admin provides to assigning users to groups. I think this is exactly what you want.

Just use `filter_horizontal = ('memberEventDay',)` in admin and you get this nice widget.